# ~ is being replaced by a variable's value in bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell, variables, scripting

So I have a script that does this

```
wget firefoxDownloadLink -o ~/firefox
mkdir ~/firefox-17
cd ~/firefox-17
tar xjf ~/firefox-17.0.1.tar.bz2
```

And I'm getting this, and have no idea why:

```
cd: context: No such file or directory
mkdir: cannot create directory `context/firefox-17': No such file or directory
cd: context/firefox-17: No such file or directory
tar (child): context/firefox-17.0.1.tar.bz2: Cannot open: No such file or directory
```

I have set a variable with the context value that is showing up there, but I don't understand why `~` is being replaced with that value. If I don't set that value it works correctly, but now I need it.

Any suggestions on what might be happening?

Comment: "I have set a variable" — That variable wouldn't happen to be `HOME`, would it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`~` is replaced with the value of `$HOME`, which normally points to your home directory. It looks like you've overridden `$HOME`.

From the bash man page:

> If a word begins with an unquoted tilde character (`~`), all of the characters preceding the first unquoted slash (or all characters, if there is no unquoted slash) are considered a tilde-prefix.  If none of the characters in the tilde-prefix are quoted, the characters in the tilde-prefix following the tilde are treated as a possible login  name.   If  this login  name  is the null string, the tilde is replaced with the value of the shell parameter `HOME`.  If `HOME` is unset, the home directory of the user executing the shell is substituted instead.  Otherwise, the tilde-prefix is replaced with the home directory associated with the specified login name.